# Get list all months and year between two date range

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an ios application in which I want to get all the list of months and year in between two dates.

For eg: the start date is today and end date is 6-Jan-2015 then the output will be  May-2016, Apr-2016, Mar-2016,.......,Feb-2015, Jan-2015 in one array and years in another array eg: 2016, 2015 like this.

When I searched I found some solution but all that solutions returns the number of months in between two dates and not exactly what i want.

I used this code

```
NSInteger month = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitMonth
                                               fromDate: yourFirstDate
                                                 toDate: yourSecondDate
                                                options: 0] month];
```

Can anyone point me to right direction. I am stuck at it for couple of hours.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *startingDate =[NSDate date] ;
NSDate *endingDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"06-Jan-2015"];

NSDateComponents *Components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *dateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *yearArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger month=1;
NSDate *nextDate = endingDate;

do {
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM-yyyy"];
    [dateArray insertObject:[formatter stringFromDate:nextDate] atIndex:0];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

    if (![yearArray containsObject:[formatter stringFromDate:nextDate]])
    {
         [yearArray insertObject:[formatter stringFromDate:nextDate] atIndex:0];
    }

    [Components setMonth:month++];
    NSDate *d = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:Components toDate:endingDate options:0];
    nextDate = d;
} while([nextDate compare:startingDate] == NSOrderedAscending);


NSLog(@"%@",dateArray);
NSLog(@"%@",yearArray);
```